# EF 6 - [One or zero] to [one or zero] relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to create a data model for an old database structure with Entity Framework 6. Here are my tables

```
class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual Child1 Child1 {get; set;}
    public virtual Child2 Child2 {get; set;}
}

class Child1
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int? ParentId {get; set;}
    public virtual Parent Parent {get; set;}
}

class Child2
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int? ParentId {get; set;}
    public virtual Parent Parent {get; set;}
}
```

Tables Child1 and Child2 have a nullable foreign key ParentId that references Parent table. Parent does not have a foreign key to children, but I still want it to have a navigation property. How could I achieve this with EF6, preferably with data annotations?

EDIT: The problem seems to be that the old database structure supports a possibility that e.g. multiple Child1 entities may refer to the same Parent, so Parent should have a list of Child1 and Child2 entities. However in practice, A Parent can only have one of each Child types, although this is not enforced by database structure. Is there a way that I can still use singular navigation properties?

Comment: Make the navigation properties nullable (`virtual Parent? Parent`).  I would also remove the ParentId properties, as they are not required (EF will add them for you) and will tempt you into loading them directly in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual Child1 Child1 {get; set;}
    public virtual Child2 Child2 {get; set;}
}

class Child1
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    ...
    public virtual Parent Parent {get; set;}
}

class Child2
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    ...
    public virtual Parent Parent {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I cannot define ParentId as [Key] for Children, because they have their own primary keys and can exist without Parent.

Comment: Usual workflow is that Child1 or Child2 is created first, and then a Parent is created for it afterwards. So parent will only have Child1, Child2 or neither.

Comment: I don't exist without my parents! You'll have to rethink that approach.